# How do you resolve a GitHub merge conflict that appears to have everything merged in?

Tags: git, github, merge

The repo I am contributing to uses a forking/rebasing pattern on GitHub. I feel like I'm missing a concept here as I did not get the result I was expecting. Currently, my PR says it can't merge because there is a conflict, however, there appears to be no commits in the `dev` branch that don't exist in mine.

The steps I took to end up here are as follows:

1. Created a fork of a repo
2. Created a branch for my feature based on dev
3. Made changes, committed files
4. Created a pull request

At this point, I got the following error from an AppVeyor message:

```
This pull request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved.
```

The recommendation was to "Pull the latest dev, rebase your PR on it."

So, from my branch I did the following two commands to update from the upstream (aspnet) and then rebase my branch off of dev:

```
git fetch aspnet
git rebase aspnet/dev
```

I expected that my branch would contain all of the commits from aspnet/dev, then my commits. Instead, my changes seem to appear twice, the other commit has appears in between them (so...there is nothing left to merge), I have no conflicts locally and I've landed in the following state:

[image: Graph of commits]

Now, my changes aren't huge - limited to a single file - and I could likely just nuke the PRs and start over, but I want to understand what I did wrong and what the "correct" way would have been to do it.

This is the PR in question: [#24 Refactored Clearing of Secrets File](https://github.com/aspnet/UserSecrets/pull/33)

Is there a way to fix what I have so the PR can merge?

Is there a better flow to follow so that the rebase works correctly?

Comment: @Amelia am I to rebase _again_? I already did once (per the message above).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there were a couple of things that I had to do.

First, `aspnet/dev` and my forked `dev` were not in sync. To get them sync'd up I did the following:

```
git fetch aspnet
git checkout dev
git rebase aspnet/dev
git push
```

Next I switched back to my branch and cleaned things up, followed by a forced push to the repo/PR:

```
git checkout misterjames/clear-corrupt-secrets
git rebase -i dev
git push -f
```

I squashed all the commits into a single commit during the interactive rebase.

Thanks to @david-paquette for his tips on solving this.